# Не выполняется onRestart()

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle

Про метод onRestart() сказано что он выполняется перед onStart если активити восстанавливается из состояния stopped. У меня в программе есть 2 активити и я хочу чтобы когда я возвращаюсь в первое(main) со второго, TextView текст которого может изменятся в первом активити сохранил изменения, а не получил значение заданное в xml файле. Но приведенный ниже код не делает этого, хотя если изменить onRestart на onStart или onResume то все заработает как надо. Так почему onRestart не работает как его аналоги?

```
Override
public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getIntExtra("i",-100)!=-100){
        i = intent.getIntExtra("i",-100);
        tvSecond.setText(intent.getStringExtra("currentString"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

проделай аналогичную процедуру с `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`